# call function that return react component

Tags: reactjs

I write a component in React and in the end, I write a function that returns component.
now, I want to show component by calling the function over my React app

my component code is :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Snackbar as MuiSnackbar, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core'
import { Close as CloseIcon, CheckCircle as CheckCircleIcon, Error as ErrorIcon, Info as InfoIcon, Warning as WarningIcon } from '@material-ui/icons'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { green, amber, red, blue } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

const toastBgColor = {
    success: green[600],
    warning: amber[700],
    error: red[400],
    info: blue[200]
}

const toastIcons = {
    success: <CheckCircleIcon />,
    warning: <WarningIcon />,
    error: <ErrorIcon />,
    info: <InfoIcon />
}

const Wrapper = styled(MuiSnackbar)`
    background-color: ${props => toastBgColor[props.bg]};
`
const Snackbar = (props) => {
    const [toastError, setToastError] = React.useState(true)

    const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
            return;
        }
        setToastError(false);
    };


    return (
        <Wrapper
            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'left' }}
            open={toastError}
            autoHideDuration={5000}
            onClose={handleClose}
            ContentProps={{
                'aria-describedby': 'message-id',
            }}
            message={<span id="message-id">{toastIcons[props.bg]}{props.message}</span>}
            action={[
                <IconButton
                    key="close"
                    aria-label="close"
                    color="inherit"
                    onClick={handleClose}
                >
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>,
            ]}
        />
    );
}


export default (bg,message)=><Snackbar bg={bg} message={message}/>
```

as the top, my component is Snackbar and the last line is my function.

now I want to by importing the top component like (import Snackbar from 'top comp')

and

call the function like this: Snackbar("success", "message") in my app, the component be run.

Comment: What's the specific issue? (And why? Why not just render the component?)

Comment: I want to act such as the react-toastify library, for example when the user can't be logged in, show message

Comment: You probably want conditional rendering then.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your idea, but I don't think that's the correct way to approach the problem in React.

I think you're coming from the Android background where you can simply call a static method to show a Snackbar, but this is not how things work in React.

In React you need to render a Snackbar somewhere and toggle it by changing the `toastError` prop between null and some other value that may go in.